# Extracting everything after the underscore and before last underscore

Tags: sas

I have a filename named “Output_DPS_BCS_FT_G”. I want to extract “DPS_BCS_FT”
Another filename named “Output_DPS_KEL_TEST_G”. I want to extract “DPS_KEL_TEST”

```
data dataset;
   set dataset;
   length filename $20.;
   first_underscore = index(filename, '_');
   last_underscore = find(reverse(filename), '_');
   extracted_text = substr(filename, first_underscore+1, length(filename)-last_underscore);
run;
```

It seem to be finding the last underscore position wrong

Answer (score 0):

Use regex:

```
extracted_text = prxChange("/[^_]*_(.*)_[^_]*$/\1/", 1, filename);
```

[See live regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/LZGOeZi5MSSNHK).

This regex matches the entire input while capturing the target and replaces the match (ie everything) with the target, effectively "extracting" it.

Answer (score 0):

`findc()` has a right to left option, `b` for backwards.
Use `substrN()` to get an empty string when criteria are not met, and also not get NOTE: in the log.

```
data have;
length filename $40;
input filename;
datalines;
Output_DPS_BCS_FT_G.dat
Output_DPS_KEL_TEST_G.txt
KC_listing.txt
;

data want;
  set have;
  p1 = indexc(filename,'_') + 1;
  p2 = findc(filename,'_','b');
  middle = substrn(filename, p1, p2-p1);
  put middle=;
run;
```